# Use dictionary on Pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda

I want to do something like the following:

```
df['Day'] = df['Day'].apply(lambda x: x + myDict[df['Month']]),
```

where

```
myDict={2:3,4:1,6:1,9:1,11:1,1:0,3:0,5:0,7:0,8:0,10:0,12:0}.
```

What I'm doing is adding a number of days onto the day of the month if it's a certain month. Ex: If it's February and the day of the month is 28, I add 3 to get 31.

But this does not work because I really want to apply myDict to the indexes of df['Month'], not the Month column directly.

Can I do iterrows inline for my command? I think this would perform faster through pandas than a big for loop iterating through the whole dataframe.

Comment: Can you show an example of your DataFrame?

Comment: I can tell you what's in it, but I can't show the customer data. I have the Month, whether it's a weekday/weekend, what day of the month, which product, what division, amount spent, etc. It's strings and integers. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I'm trying to figure-out is what *indexes of df['Month']* means in your question. What does such an index look like?

Comment: @piRsquared just answered it. He said use df.Day += df.Month.map(myDict). And Month is an int from 1 to 12.

Comment: He changed his answer based on the "index" line in your question. Which one is correct?

Comment: The first one. I appreciate the quick change, but it was just poor terminology on my part. Apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df.Day += df.Month.map(myDict)
```

Or:
because I don't really get what you are doing

```
df.Day += df.index.to_series().map(myDict)
```

Comment: OP states: *I really want to apply myDict to the indexes of df['Month'], not the Month column directly.* I'm trying to figure-out what these indexes are.

Comment: the original answer of df.Day += df.Month.map(myDict) changes each row correctly. I do not think the df.index.to_series().map(myDict) works because it has no reference to df.Month! By index I meant to say all row values of the column where being addressed. I do not know that index is the proper term.

Comment: @lasingallday The term you're looking for is simply the *values*. An *index* (in any programming language) refers to the *location* of a value. That's why we were confused.